# Early warning system for car crashes?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acoustics, everyday-life, frequency, spectroscopy

Like the sound system used for recognizing and locating gunshots([gunfire locator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunfire_locator)) could one be built for car accidents? Even though a car accident has a much wider range of potential sound could enough shared frequency occur after a curtain force upon all cars give a unique sound signature where an emergency team could locate where an accident happens instantly? The EMTs makes the decision if an air medivac is called. We can statically say if an accident occur with enough pressure injuries are consistent. What if it is a single car crash happens where no one hears it. A system like this would save lives and greatly cut response time.

We wouldn't have to send a team for every loud bang just take a look if unreported or isolated if its much more than common decimals found by construction or logging. At least they could be stored as data for useful info like a more diverse seismograph.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sufficiently dense array of microphones, coupled with a deep learning algorithm that "learns" the sound of car crashes by analyzing millions of hours of "not car crash" and thousands of "car crash" sounds, would in principle be capable of achieving reasonable accuracy in detecting the sound you are after.

But this would require extraordinarily dense array of microphones (to get sufficient signal to noise ratio, you need to be within 100 m or so of the crash site) and according to your reasoning, you would need it "on every road".

There are about 4.3 million km of paved roads in the US, so you would need 43 million microphone arrays. Assume that each is sampling at 10 kHz, 16 bits, you could process the signal locally (to prevent the need for 800 gigabytes of data per second being sent to a central server).

Now let's assume that ony second, this algorithm has a 1 in a billion chance of mischaracterizing a sound as a crash. That's an astonishingly low probability. But with 43 million microphones, we would get one false alarm every 23 seconds.

Which would overwhelm any central response system very quickly.

It's the scale of the problem that makes your proposed approach so impractical. You could build a single detector at the junction outside of your house, and it could ring a bell when there is a crash. And you might never get a false alarm.

There is an interesting, and related, problem in statistics. Given a low prevalence of a particular condition ("car crash") and a low probability of a false positive ("heard a crash when there wasn't one"), what is the probability that a crash happened given that you heard one?

There are approximately 5 million car crashes per year in the USA, so the probability of an individual station (in 43 million) being close to a crash in a given year is approximately 12 %. The chance of a "fake" detection, at 1 in a billion every second, times the number of seconds in a year, is 3%. So if a crash is detected, there would be 3 false alarms for every 12 true crashes. The "one in a billion" error rate becomes a 20% error rate, with these numbers.

This is a well known (and non-intuitive) problem with medical screening. If you have a prevalence of a disease of 1%, and a 95% accurate test, then when someone tests positive there is a very large chance they don't have the disease: if you test 100 people, 5 people will be wrongly told they have the disease, and one person will actually have the disease. Meaning that the success rate of the "95% accurate" test is only 1 in 6.

Answer (score 1):

If we think about saving lives in the time of car crashes then we shouldn't reply on inefficient systems like the one suggested. It's hard to apply and build to be effective.

If you rely on a sound based system then you'd need additional resources to locate the exact position where the car crashed. Even if the frequencies involved in a car crash would be decisive in determining that "a car did crash" but a minor crash in a nearby location would produce the same loudness as a major crash in a farther location. To triangulate the exact location you would need a lot of those systems to be installed in a "grid" like way. So this system sounds pretty inefficient.

A better way would be installing systems in the car itself that could detect pressure change, or some sort of mechanism that triggers only during a crash. Nowadays all cars have GPS systems and it would be easier to send an SOS signal to the nearest units based on the reports of the machine installed in the car itself.